# Get average time per a visit

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is get the average page_visit_duration but for some of the rows have the same session_id any row with a duplicate session id just means the visitor visited multiple pages  for those rows with the same session_id I need to add up the total page_visit_duration of all pages they visited  before getting the average time spent on the site  how can I do this I searched and I couldn't find anything.

Here's the queries I tried:

```
select avg(page_visit_duration) as avgtime from page_views 

select avg(page_visit_duration) as avgtime from page_views group by `session_id`
```

please note the second query returns back many results I need it to give back 1 average

What I'm trying to do is to get the average time spent on our site per a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first group your results, and take the average of those.

```
SELECT avg(total_duration) as avgtime FROM 
   (SELECT sum(page_visit_duration) as total_duration, session_id FROM page_views group by session_id) sq
```

Comment: Hey Scott, Thanks  is this query  calculating  the time for all the visit durations including the visit durations that have only one session_id or just the visits that have duplicate session ids?

Comment: All sessions -- not just duplicates.   The inner query first sums durations by session id - and the outer query averages those.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to calculate the total amount of time and divide by the number of sessions:

```
select sum(page_visit_duration) / count(distinct session_id) as avgtime
from page_views
group by `session_id`;
```